# Silverlight Form View Issue

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that dynamically creates a form. Within this form I have my application working so that the tab focus is in order of the form. 
The issue I have is that the form is quite large (below the screen view) and when I tab to the lower items the screen does not adjust therefore I need to scroll down the page to where my tab focus is.

Does anyone know how to set the form so that the item which has focus is always in the centre of the screen.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy or AutoMagical way to do this.  Since you appear to be dynamically creating the controls yourself you are in a position to be attaching an event handler to each of the relevant control's `GotFocus` event.

Your mention of "scroll down the page" may indicate you are placing these controls in a `ScrollViewer` control (if not change your code so that you are).

Your controls are being placed in `Panel` which is the child of the `ScrollViewer`.

So the task for the `GotFocus` event handler is discover the vertical position of the control relative to the panel then with a few other calcs call the `ScrollViewer` `ScrollToVerticalOffset` method.

```
private void FormControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    GeneralTranform transform = fe.Transform(myContainingPanel);
    Point topLeft = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    myScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(topLeft.Y - (myScrollViewer.ViewportHeight / 2) + (fe.ActualHeight / 2) );
}
```